# Can a structural directive context contain a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I created a simple structural directive to assist in generating unique ids for some custom components.

```
import { Directive, DoCheck, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

export class UniqueIdContext {
  constructor(private $implicit: string) {}

  at(index: number) {
    return `${this.$implicit}_${index}`;
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[uniqueId]'
})
export class UniqueIdDirective implements DoCheck {
  @Input()
  set uniqueIdFor(uniqueIdFor: string) {
    this._uniqueIdFor = uniqueIdFor;
    this._uniqueIdDirty = true;
  }

  private _uniqueIdFor: string;
  private _uniqueIdDirty = false;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<UniqueIdContext>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this._uniqueIdDirty) {
      this._uniqueIdDirty = false;
      const prefix = uuid();
      const name = this._uniqueIdFor;
      const id = `${prefix}_${name}`.replace(/-/g, '');
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(
        this.templateRef,
        new UniqueIdContext(id)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```html
<div *uniqueId="let id for 'control'">
  <input [attr.id]="id" [formControl]="control">
  <label [attr.for]="id">My Label</label>
</div>
```

This works well if I want to use the id as-is. However, I intend to use this within an `ngFor` loop to generate ids for controls at each iteration, it would suffix the index to the generated id.  That's what the `UniqueIdContext.at()` function was intended to do, but it doesn't seem to work.

```html
<ul *uniqueId="let id for 'control'">
  <li *ngFor="let control of controls; index as i">
    <input [attr.id]="at(i)" [formControl]="control">
    <label [attr.for]="at(i)">My Label {{i}}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I also tried `id.at(i)` and `id(i)` but doesn't work. I'd like to keep this all contained within this directive/context.

Do I need to declare the template variable somehow? How can I make this work?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by making the `$implicit` variable a function to get the generated id. The function would be created in the directive but this feels hacky to me. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7hidfy?file=src/app/directives/unique-id.directive.ts)

Comment: Even changing at function to arrow function also working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the main restriction here was the use of `this`. I would need to bind the method to `this`, then declare a template variable for it.

```
export class UniqueIdContext {
  constructor(private $implicit: string) {
    this.at = this.at.bind(this);
  }

  at(index?: number) {
    return index != null ? `${this.$implicit}_${index}` : this.$implicit;
  }
}
```

```
<ul *uniqueId="let id for 'control'; at as idAt">
  <li *ngFor="let control of controls; index as i">
    <input [attr.id]="idAt(i)" [formControl]="control">
    <label [attr.for]="idAt(i)">My Label {{i}}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```